# Why is there lagging with query animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a simple scroll animation, followed by another scaling animation when the scroll reaches certain point. when scrolled back up it is supposed to return to original state. I understand there might be some queuing problem, how can I solve this? 
First the animation is lagging really bad, specially if you do it on a local computer, then the commented out code is not working. I want it to return to the original state when scrolled back up.

https://codepen.io/alexiirj/pen/xpLeve

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(window).scroll(function(){
       $('.coverBottom').css('transform', 'translate3d(0,' + $(this).scrollTop()*2 + 'px, 0)');
       if($(window).scrollTop()){
            $('.x').animate({height: '100%', width: '100%'}, 'slow');
        }
        // if($(window).scroll() == 0){
        //  $('.SecondImg').css({height: '200px', width: '200px'});
        // }
    }).scroll();
});
```

Comment: The lag is caused by the fact that the `scroll` event fires for every pixel that the element is scrolled by, ie. scroll 1000px, that's 1000 times your `.coverBottom` element is updated in the DOM (assuming your computer is quick enough to catch all the events - some are skipped). There's not a 'fix all' solution to this. Generally it's best to perform animation in CSS though, as it's hardware accelerated whereas JS is not.

Comment: That is correct. I was not aware about the queue, and the step by step javascript procedure. I will write it in CSS3, thank you.

Comment: invoking css3 animation through javascript, will I still get that slowness?

Comment: No, that's the best way to use animation.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll listener event inside another scroll listener is causing this slowness.
There’s no native JavaScript event for when scrolling stops, but it is something you can detect pretty easily with just a few lines of code.

```
    // Setup isScrolling variable
var isScrolling;

// Listen for scroll events
window.addEventListener('scroll', function ( event ) {

    // Clear our timeout throughout the scroll
    window.clearTimeout( isScrolling );

    // Set a timeout to run after scrolling ends
    isScrolling = setTimeout(function() {

        // Run the callback
        console.log( 'Scrolling has stopped.' );

    }, 66);

}, false);
```